# How to load R packages with versions as specified in DESCRIPTION?

Tags: r, r-package

As I contribute to open-sourced R packages, they often have specific dependencies requirement specified in `DESCRIPTION`. This could cause:

1. code breaking,
2. different `testthat` versions failing tests that should pass
3. different `roxygen2` versions rewriting the `DESCRIPTION` and `NAMESPACE`.

What's the most convenient way during my development workflow to load these specific versions of the dependencies?